# Getting NullPointerException in Android SDK's method updateLocaleListFromAppContext

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app uploaded on PlayStore and getting crash on it `java.lang.NullPointerException` from `android.app.ActivityThread.updateLocaleListFromAppContext`

I have tried searching a lot online to check where this error could be coming from. I'm not natively using this method call specifically for anything in the code.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.updateLocaleListFromAppContext (ActivityThread.java:5892)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:6127)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200 (ActivityThread.java:240)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1797)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7076)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:494)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

Please help if anyone knows the solution or where I can start looking to resolve this.

To clarify, this is not an issue of how to avoid a common NullPointerException, this does not happen in the developers code but rather on the side of Android API itself and the question is on how to avoid it, as it cannot be resolved directly. The issue still exists.

Comment: In crash log u can find the java class and line number

Comment: I have pasted the crash log i obtained from the playstore in my question. The error is in default android classes.

Comment: I found something xda developers site  https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=72836226&postcount=581

Comment: No solution on that forum link as well @VinothKumarSubramani

Comment: 2 years later, I'm also seeing that issue on Android 9, and sadly no indication on its root cause. Any progress on finding a solution?

Comment: Same here. For me the issue started appearing abruptly 1 week ago. Unable to detect where it's coming from. It only happens on OnePlus devices.

Comment: I'm getting this error heavily on Samsung J series devices running Android 9.

Comment: and still there.. and only on OnePlus

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60629355/13600988 Found the same error that's resolved by converting bitmap to byte array before passing in intent. It May be that you too are trying to pass bitmap directly with intent.

Comment: @ShubhamAgrawal I didn't pass any bitmap with intent but I'm still getting this error from Firebase Crashlytics, I don't think it is related to bitmap. I got this error on Vsmart Joy 3 running Android10. (Unfortunately, I don't own a Vsmart and I can't reproduce the error)

Comment: still there... so far only seen on OnePlus5, Android 9

Comment: same here...this NPE just appeared for me on a "UMIDIGI Bison GT" using Android 10.
Judging from stacktrace, i can only guess that it has something to do with localization...
Happened for just one user on said device.

Comment: the method that updatelocale one is called to Decides whether to update an Activity's configuration and whether to inform it. so probably has to do with either config change or inntent where activity are reloading

Comment: You need to check all variables and methods. Also, if you are using third-party SDKs, then you must make sure that their methods cannot return null, or that you handle them correctly.


You can also use this [service](https://www.browserstack.com/) as an emulator. It seems there are versions of smartphones and which this error occurs.

Comment: The java.lang.NullPointerException from android.app.ActivityThread.updateLocaleListFromAppContext() is a known issue in Android. It is caused by a bug in the Android API itself, and it cannot be resolved directly by developers.

Answer (score 1):

Upon checking the question comments and in which devices this issue occurs, it appears it is specific to a subset of devices, such as OnePlus devices, and Samsung J series. The common part is for them to be Android 9 devices. I've examined the source code for Android 9 ([here is the method call](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/pie-release/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java#L5750) which is at line 5750 and [here is the method itself](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/pie-release/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java#L5520) which is at line 5520) and I can say this code is not related to configuration changes. While the links' line numbers are not exactly the same, they are related in the distance (e.g. **5750 - 5520 = 280** which is from the source code, and **6127 - 5892 = 285** which is from the stack trace. Quite close but not exact) so I am assuming the framework is calling that part. The method, `ActivityThread.handleBindApplication` is called at first launch, and configuration changes happen only with activity recreations, the app's configuration does not change. At least, the given method is not called again.

I can also say that the method `updateLocaleListFromAppContext` was successfully called and the code crashed inside the method, not at the start.

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```java
/**
 * The LocaleList set for the app's resources may have been shuffled so that the preferred
 * Locale is at position 0. We must find the index of this preferred Locale in the
 * original LocaleList.
 */
private void updateLocaleListFromAppContext(Context context, LocaleList newLocaleList) {
    final Locale bestLocale = context.getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0);
    final int newLocaleListSize = newLocaleList.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < newLocaleListSize; i++) {
        if (bestLocale.equals(newLocaleList.get(i))) {
            LocaleList.setDefault(newLocaleList, i);
            return;
        }
    }

    // The app may have overridden the LocaleList with its own Locale
    // (not present in the available list). Push the chosen Locale
    // to the front of the list.
    LocaleList.setDefault(new LocaleList(bestLocale, newLocaleList));
}
```

Now, there are a couple of things to consider,

- This is taken from AOSP (Open source project) and device manufacturers usually modify these core classes. The method inside the devices may have been modified, but it is a low possibility.
- Google Play Console can sometimes trim out the information about the stack trace.
- If the stack trace is exact, this method can only crash at `newLocaleList.size()` and `bestLocale.equals(newLocaleList.get(i))` calls. The reason for that is: that when the stack traces are generated, their exception always contains the last code, and other lines would've left another stack trace.
- Another possibility is: that because of the for loop and the usage of `newLocaleListSize`, the `newLocaleList` variable's size could've been changed while the code was iterating, causing the crash at `newLocaleList.get(i)`. This one is a bit more unlikely though, since the `get(i)` method would've been visible on crash, assuming the data is complete.

Based on the info, the most likely culprits are the variables `bestLocale` and `newLocaleList` in the method. Upon examining the source code more, the `newLocaleList` variable which is passed, is created via `AppBindData` which is passed down via a handler, and its information is updated in `handleBindApplication`. The method calls specific information updates using Android's **PackageManager**, which is used to query information about the APK / loaded app, such as its info, manifest data, metadata, activities, etc...

This information is usually delivered from the system to the app using IPC (or AIDL) and that information can sometimes get corrupt, causing this error. Thus, it may be possible that `newLocaleList` variable is null.

Since this is a problem in the system, to possibly avoid it I can only suggest a couple of things:

- Analyze the devices themselves if possible and see if the app crashes in the debug build,
- Ensure your strings are completely converted in all languages and you do not rely on the default language (a.k.a primary language that has all the strings but the specific configurations do not have them unless they are marked with `translatable=false` in the `strings.xml` file)
- Check if a similar report exists in Firebase Crashlytics if it is used (it may not be there since the app is crashing before the app is properly created but Firebase services can still upload sometimes. It can also contain more info about the stack trace.)
- Check if the crash occurs in Android 9 Emulator (the official emulator **and** a Genymotion emulator)
- You can also use an online Samsung device from [Samsung Test Lab](https://developer.samsung.com/remote-test-lab) (albeit for a short time) and see if the crash is observable. You might get a complete stack trace and it could point you in the right direction.

These are my findings, hopefully, they are useful in some way.