# Issue in android updateLocaleListFromAppContext NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Recently my app crashed and showed the below error. I can't detect what the actual issue is, and also can't detect crash.

If anyone has a solution for this crash then help for this issue.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.updateLocaleListFromAppContext (ActivityThread.java:6107)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:6354)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300 (ActivityThread.java:220)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1860)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7403)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:492)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:935)
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I think the issue with layout or something that not in c java class.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

After a crash analysis and check firebase crashlytics I got the solution of my error.
Actual I pass image one activity to another activity and its crash being there.

**Activity A**

```
Intent code = new Intent(Activity_A.this, Activity_B.class);
code.putExtra("BitmapImage", bitmap);
startActivity(code);
```

**Activity B**

And I retrieve the image in another class

```
if (getIntent()!= null) {
    bitmap = (Bitmap) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
}
```

**Solution is**: convert bitmap to byte array after pass one activity to another activity like below

**Activity A:**

```
Intent code = new Intent(Activity_A.this, Activity_B.class);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
code.putExtra("BitmapImage", byteArray);
startActivity(code);
```

**Activity B:**

```
Bundle extras;

if (intent != null) {
  extras = getIntent().getExtras();
  byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("BitmapImage");
  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
}
```

After this code, my issue is solved  :)

Comment: I don't see how the changes you made has anything to do with the crash, which is in this function: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r60/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java#5520